# Rails ordering of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to order a list of categories by the category's parent's parent. 
Item is an attribute of a Category, indicating the category has a parent, and that parent also has a parent, and that parent has no parent.

Here is some non-working code, but that hopefully lets you see what I am after.

```
Category.item.order(parent.parent_id: :asc)
```

Here are the details of the model.

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :organization
   belongs_to :parent, class_name: Category
   has_many :subcategories, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: Category, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: I recommend using scopes inside your Model: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes